# how to set from address according to the form input email address for wp_mail()?

Tags: forms, wp-mail, html-email

I am trying to create form and send it to my e-mail address using wp_mail.
my wp_mail() code is:

```
if($_POST["submit"]) {
    $to="my email";
    $subject ="My subject";     
    $sender=$_POST["sendername"];
    $senderEmail=$_POST["senderEmail"];
    $message=$_POST["message"];
    $name_title=$_POST["name_title"];   

    $mailBody = "<b><span style='color: red;'>Name:</span></b> $name_title $sender\n<br/>
                 <b>Email:</span></b> $senderEmail\n\n<br/><br/>
                 <b>Message:</b> $message";

    $mail_sent = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $mailBody );
    }
```

and for changing the from address I've added the following filters into my functions.php

```
/* adding support for html emails*/
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type','wpse27856_set_content_type' );
function wpse27856_set_content_type(){
    return "text/html";
}

/* from address */
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', 'my_mail_from' );
function my_mail_from( $email )
{
    return $senderEmail;
}

/* from name*/
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', 'my_mail_from_name' );
function my_mail_from_name( $name )
{
    return $sender;
}
```

and the form HTML is:

```
<form id="" name="" action="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" method="post">
<div class="form-input">
    <select name="name_title" class="name-title-input">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select Title</option>
    <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
</div>
<div class="label-input-wrapper">
        <div class="form-label">Name</div><div class="form-input"><input type="text" name="sendername"/></div>
    </div>

    <div class="label-input-wrapper">
        <div class="form-label">E-Mail</div><div class="form-input"><input type="email" name="senderEmail" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" required /></div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

It's not sending the mail form to my email. but It sends form to my email if I change the filters as following:

```
/* from address */
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', 'my_mail_from' );
function my_mail_from( $email )
{
    return "my@email.com";
}

/* from name*/
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', 'my_mail_from_name' );
function my_mail_from_name( $name )
{
    return "my name";
}
```

So how can make it possible to get the senders  email on from header?

Comment: It looks like a problem with the **scope** of your variables, check for example [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) PHP doc page. PS: I don't see any validation/sanitazion in your example!

Comment: I am checking the code. If all ok I'll move to validation part. and I do not find the variable errors here...

Comment: I think you should use [WP_DEBUG while testing](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)  on your dev install, but your `$senderEmail` and `$sender` variables are not defined within your functions, since these variables are defined in the global scope.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If I'm understanding you right you just are having trouble getting the from set? The easiest way would just be adding the **from** in the **email headers** in the **wp_mail** function.

Here is an example of one of my old simple email sending functions that works:

```
function contact_send() {
    $title   = 'New message Received';
    $headers = array('From: '.$_POST['full_name'].' <'.$_POST['email_address'].'>');
    $message = '<h1>My message</h1>';

    //Send the email
    add_filter('wp_mail_content_type', create_function('', 'return "text/html"; '));
    $email = wp_mail('my_email@email.com', $title, $message, $headers);
    remove_filter('wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type');

    return $email;
}
```

The **wp_mail_from** hook provides the email you have already set in your **wp_mail** function, you have not set one so it was receiving blank and sending back an empty variable ($senderEmail was not defined so would return undefined).

Comment: Woooh... that's great man.. this line save me.. `$headers = array('From: '.$_POST['sendername'].' <'.$_POST['senderEmail'].'>');` and I removed `wp_mail_from`filter and `wp_mail_from_name` Now I'm getting exact the from sender's name and it's sender email on mail header..

Comment: I always used to do this, but it's not a good idea anymore. You get flagged as spam sending email from addresses if you aren't explicitly authorized. So I started sending from a site address and setting a Replyto: header instead of From:

Answer (score 8):

For this filtering the email address:

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', 'my_mail_from_name' );
function my_mail_from_name( $name ) {
    return "My Name";
}
```

Now add a filter for the name of the email address:

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', 'my_mail_from' );
function my_mail_from( $email ) {
    return "change-this-to-your-email-address";
}
```

into your `function.php`.

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem? Note the the OP wanted to use a specific **variable** in these functions.

Comment: worked for me! thanks.
I would like just to add that `function.php.`is found in your  theme directory under `/wp-content/themes/`