# How to retrieve the sender email with wp_mail()?

Tags: php, email, wp-mail

I Have this simple following code :

```
<?php
//if "email" variable is filled out, send email
if (isset($_POST['email']))  {
    //Email information
    $to = get_option( 'admin_email' );
    $headers = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    //send email
    wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    //Email response
    echo "Thank you for contacting us!";
}

    //if "email" variable is not filled out, display the form
    else  {
?>
<form method="post">
    Email: <input name="email" type="text" /><br />
    Subject: <input name="subject" type="text" /><br />
    Message:<br />
    <textarea name="message" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>

<?php
  }
?>
```

My question is how to retrieve the sender email instead of the generated `wp_mail()` from $header `wordpress@$sitename` ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You get the email from `$_POST['email']`. Did you want this to show up as the "From" email address?

Comment: @czerspalace I don't get the `$_POST['email']` and this is driving me crazy... I'm getting the generated `wp_mail()` from header, like so :
**From : WordPress : wordpress@mysiteurl.domainname**
I want to get the sender email as expected...

Comment: You are not setting the From address anywhere.. Review this question to see how to set http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/160017/how-to-set-from-address-according-to-the-form-input-email-address-for-wp-mail

Comment: Thanks for the link, I've seen it before but still unable to make it work.

Comment: Did you change the `$headers` to match what is in the link? If so, please edit question and post your updated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've learned an **expensive (time)** lesson.
The next time I'll want to set a contact form, I'll **first** check the host servers specific configuration regarding Email settings !
Thanks to [Steve North](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/97070/steve-north), I understood that my host doesn't allow **direct custom $headers** for security reason...
But, I think that, every decent host has solutions for their customers.
So, if your are on Name Cheap (that's my case), you can refer to this article [How to configure Contact Form hosted with us](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9239/31/how-to-configure-contact-form-hosted-with-us)

Hope that this will help others. SYA :)

Comment: And chance you could add this as an edit to your original answer and mark mine as correct?

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the from address.

You can do the following:

```
<?php
//if "email" variable is filled out, send email
if (isset($_POST['email']))  {
    //Email information
    $to = get_option( 'admin_email' );
    $headers = array('From: Me Myself <'.$_POST['email'].'>'); //updated
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    //send email
    wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    //Email response
    echo "Thank you for contacting us!";
}

    //if "email" variable is not filled out, display the form
    else  {
?>
<form method="post">
    Email: <input name="email" type="text" /><br />
    Subject: <input name="subject" type="text" /><br />
    Message:<br />
    <textarea name="message" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
```

As you can see, the $headers uses an array that contains the text 'From:' to set the from header.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hello @Steve North, thanks a lot for your help, but I have already try it and it's not working. The message is not sent at all... **WEIRD**...

Comment: Sorry, got it a little wrong.. It should be: 

$headers = array('From: Me Myself <'.$_POST['email'].'>');

See here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/

Comment: I've just tried your suggestion, not sending the message at all... I've memorized the wp_mail() functions and looked at the core so many times... Thanks again for your help

Comment: Have you tried it like so: $headers[] = 'From: Me Myself <'.$_POST['email'].'>';

Comment: Just tried your second suggestion, message is not sent at all... Did you take a look at the link in the previous comments ? Somehow it's working for others... Thanks again.

Comment: Do you have sendmail setup correctly on your server?

Comment: Try var_dump(wp_mail()) and see what gets returned.

Comment: `var_dump(wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers));` returns `**bool(false)** Thank you for contacting us!` Why is it working in the original form ?...

Comment: Your sending is returning false. Does it return true without $headers?

If so, your host may only allow to headers.

See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/216482/wp-mail-returning-false-on-server

Comment: BINGO, I'm on namecheap...
I didn't know about this...
Thanks a million time Steve, saved my saturday, your great. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries! Have a good weekend bud.